# マルチインデックスの列名をまとめて変更する方法

Tags: python, pandas

上段のようなDataFrameから、列名を変更して下段のようにしたいです。
行、列ともに件数が多く、可変長なため、
可能であれば、一括して変更したいのですが、forループを利用せずに列名を一括して変更することはできないでしょうか？

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# 変更前のDataFrame
data = """\
level_0,りんご,りんご,ミカン,ミカン
level_1,2018,2019,2018,2019
0,100,120,50,60
1,105,125,51,61
2,110,130,52,62
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=0, header=[0,1])
display(df)

# 変更後のDataFrame（期待する結果）
data = """\
level_0,りんご,りんご,ミカン,ミカン
level_1,2018,2022,2018,2022
0,100,120,50,60
1,105,125,51,61
2,110,130,52,62
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=0, header=[0,1])
print('↓↓↓以下のように列名を一括して変更したいです。')
display(df)
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この記事を適用して [pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) を使えば出来るでしょう。
[Rename MultiIndex columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41221079/9014308)

質問のDataFrameはlevel_1の値が同じものの繰り返しなのでこうなるのでは？

```
df.columns.set_levels([2018,2022],level=1,inplace=True)
```

---

変更する元のデータをDataFrame自身から取ってくるには、以下が使えるでしょう。
level_1が同じ値の繰り返しの時
[pandas.MultiIndex.levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.levels.html)

こんな風に：

```
lv1name = list(df.columns.levels[1])
```

level_1がすべて別の値の時
[pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html)

こんな風に：

```
lv1name = list(df.columns.get_level_values('level_1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

教えていただいた方法で、できました。ありがとうございました。

```
import io
import pandas as pd

# 変更前のDataFrame
data = """\
level_0,りんご,りんご,ミカン,ミカン
level_1,2018,2019,2018,2019
0,100,120,50,60
1,105,125,51,61
2,110,130,52,62
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), index_col=0, header=[0,1])
display(df)

level1_name_list = [ column_name.replace('2019', '2022') for column_name in df.columns.levels[1] ]
df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(level1_name_list, level=1)
display(df)
```